# How do I get hosts to access each other on a LAN when they use an access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

When two of my hosts are  connected to my main router, they can ping each other and access servers on HTTP.

When they are connected to (the same) access point, they cannot ping or access each other, though they have the same subnet mask, and `arp -a` shows that they recognize each other.

I need that access point to extend Wifi range. How do I get them to connect when they are using the access point?

Linssid screenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, fix your security. Enable WPA2-PSK (a.k.a WPA2 Personal) AES-CCMP **ONLY**. No original WPA or TKIP. Do this on both APs. Mismatched security modes can break multicast and broadcast, which can break ARP and service discovery protocols.

Then look to see if either of your APs has a "client isolation" feature enabled, and disable it.

Also make sure your secondary AP is not doing NAT or acting as a DHCP server. Only your main router should be doing that.

Comment: OK, I did it, and the two connect?. BUt Main router: WPA2-PSK, AES. Access Point
- WPA2, PSK, AES
- Access Point mode is Enabled, and the text in the admin interface  says that this disables NAT.

Comment: Thanks! They can access each other? But how do I verify which AP my host is connected to, so I can be sure? For example, does Linssid show this somehow? arp?

   (Main router: WPA2-PSK, AES. Access Point WPA2, PSK, AES.  (Access Point mode is Enabled, and the text in the admin interface  says that this disables NAT.))

Comment: Your client machine's Wi-Fi software probably has a place to see the "BSSID" of the current AP it is connected to. The BSSID is the AP's wireless MAC address (wireless Ethernet hardware address).

Comment: How can BSSID be found in Ubuntu? In the GUI, clicking on the SSID and the gear Icon, I get info like IP .but not BSSID.